# Fuelphp Save delete relation, Observer calls before_update but not before_delete

Tags: orm, fuelphp

I have an Observer on a has_many relationship like this:

```
Post has_many Comments
```

and `Comments` has the following `Observer` activated:

```
class Observer_Comments
{
    public function before_delete($model)
    {
        Log::info("Deleted a comment");
    }
    public function before_update($model)
    {
        Log::info("Updated a comment");
    }
}
```

When I update my `Post` model like this:

```
$post = Post::find(1)->related('comments);
unset($post->comments[1]);
$post->save();
```

My log does not show any activity. The `Comment` is deleted, and the `Post` is updated correctly, including running any of *its* observers.

When I delete a comment explicitly:

```
$comment = Comment::find(1);
$comment->delete();
```

then the log shows what I expect:

```
INFO --> Deleted a Comment
```

Is there a `cascade` setting I have to use?

---

UPDATE

I see this code inside of `Model::save()`:

```
1127    if (method_exists($rel, 'delete_related'))
1128    {
1129        $rel->delete_related($this);
1130    }
```

Does a `delete_related` method need to be added to my `Post` or `Comments` model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unset() doesn't delete the related object, it unsets the relation between the two.

In case of a many-many, this will also mean the record in the junction table linking the two will be deleted, in other relations the foreign key will be reset to NULL.

Both operations don't alter the data of the object, so an UPDATE will not be triggered on the object, and therefore the observers will not be called.

"cascade" means that if you delete an object, the delete will "cascade" to the related object, deleting that too. But only if you delete the "parent" in the relation, not when you unset it (which doesn't delete anything).

Comment: Ah I see the relationship is unset, but the record is not deleted. Okay, makes sense. How can I set this up so the item is deleted (or soft-deleted)?

Comment: set 'cascade_delete' to true on the relation definition.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think that will only apply if I delete the parent record, not if I just remove the relationship.

Comment: If you want to delete an item, just delete it? It will be removed from any relations automatically, if relevant.